# Descent Campaign Shortening

Tags: house-rules, descent

Myself and some friends meet up for some games every so often, and enjoy a good game of Descent to Darkness.

We recently tried a campaign over an extra long weekend (the idea of carrying equipment and characters over to a new game sounded appealing) but found that we'd barely scratched the surface, and that a lot of time was spent setting up and messing around in markets etc.

Does anyone have any recommendations (or even better, tested method) for a middle ground between an evening's single dungeon and full-on month-lasting campaign?

Comment: I've only played Descent a couple time, but it does seem like the games have lasted weeks...  While I'm not sure that there is a good way to shorten the campaign, there are a few websites that will save your data (characters, location, etc) so that you can put the game away and then come back to it later...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While this may seem disappointing, my advice is: don't.

Descent is a great game in its single-dungeon mode, and while it might look appealing to bring your characters from a dungeon to another, it actually "just doesn't work".

One of the fun things about this game is the weapon progression: as you go on, you might find cooler weapons to use. This works well in a single dungeon, but is crap in the campaign: after just a few encounters it is likely that every player will have the best-in-slot weapon for that campaign level, and anything else they can find will just be sold away. This takes away a lot of fun from the game.

Moreover due to setting and stuff you end up wasting so much time playing just a couple of (short) encounters in the campaign, that you could have played a whole (much longer) dungeon in the standard game.

If you really want to keep a few things from one dungeon to another, you could keep the same characters, follow the standard rules about xp and progression, and change a character with another one if he dies.

Comment: Ooh, reincarnation; now there's an idea. It also gives a good hefty penalty for getting yourself eaten.

Comment: If you are really having every player having the best-in-cycle weapons after just an encounter or two in the advanced campaign, then you're doing it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

With the Road to Legend or Sea of Blood campaigns you can start the campaigns at the silver or gold level to make them go much faster.

I think the campaigns are designed for about 20 hours per campaign level so starting at a each higher level cuts about 20 hours.